# getContext() doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, symbols

So I have been going through the Android Developer training on the official site and there is a point where they want us to finally instantiate our database.

So they tell us to use this snippet of code:

```
FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getContext());
```

However, I'm getting an error for the `getContext()` method. It states that it cannot find a symbol for that method.

So I searched the source and that method in the View class just cannot be found. Is this a deprecated method? And if this isn't an option, is there any other way we can grab the context of a view?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a typo: `geContext()`. Is this already your problem?

Comment: It depends on where you use this snippet. Is it inside activity or fragment or just plain class?

Comment: @SME_Dev if that was the whole problem i'll die laughting.

Comment: What type of class is from you are try construct instance, Activity, Service, etc?

Comment: it would match the error description, because "symbol not found" indicates a syntax error. Anyhow, a little more code would hlep to find the solution.

Comment: @SME_Dev Nah. That's not the problem. I just decided to type it again instead of copying and pasting it.

Comment: @BharathMg It's an activity class.

Comment: Then just add `this` instead of getContext()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line of code you pass is:

```
FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(geContext());
```

It should work if you substitute for any of these code lines :

```
FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getContext());
```

Or

```
FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

Or

```
FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(this);
```

The android developer documentation of the Context:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

You might found helpful too look in this question, that explains what is Context for:

[What is 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have used geContext() change it to `getContext()` or `getApplicationContext()` or if calling the object from inside an activity simply pass `this`

Answer (score 0):

The View class does have a [getContext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29) method.

You either have a typo, or your code is not located in a non-static method of a sub-class of View.

Comment: Can I use getContext in a class that is extended by other classes?                                                                                                          **It is getting me errors:**
http://snag.gy/hOPXk.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Thats how I made it

1. MainActivity

   FeedReaderContract contract = new FeedReaderContract(this);
2. I edited the constructor of the class FeedReaderContract

   mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getContext());
3. The method getContext()

   public Context getContext() {
       return context;
   }

Comment: Please, add a description of the solution you are proposing.