# MPAndroidChart, set different color to bar in a bar chart based on y axis values

Tags: android

I'm plotting a bar chart using MPAndroid chart. Now all my bars have the same color but I want different colors for the bars based on Y axis values, like if value >100. color = red, like in the picture below. Is that possible? someone please help me.

[image]

Regards.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can override the BarDataSet class to achieve this

```
public class MyBarDataSet extends BarDataSet {


    public MyBarDataSet(List<BarEntry> yVals, String label) {
        super(yVals, label);
    }

    @Override
    public int getColor(int index) {
        if(getEntryForXIndex(index).getVal() < 95) // less than 95 green
            return mColors.get(0);
        else if(getEntryForXIndex(index).getVal() < 100) // less than 100 orange
            return mColors.get(1);
        else // greater or equal than 100 red
            return mColors.get(2);
    }

}
```

And you need to define your colors like this:

```
MyBarDataSet set = new MyBarDataSet(yVals, "");
set.setColors(new int[]{ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green), 
                ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.orange), 
                ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)});
ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
dataSets.add(set);


BarData data = new BarData(xVals, dataSets);
```

Comment: Make sure on the dataset, that you dont also call set.setColor(..). This will make it so the getColor is never called.

Comment: @m4n3k4s This is the most ever needed solution for a BarChart where bar color depends on Y values. Thanks + 10.

Comment: BarData data = new BarData(xVals, set);? because dataSets is not assigning.

Comment: I'm using this, getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark),  but this seems deprecated...is there another line of code I could use to replace with?  I'm just trying to get different colors like YELLOW, but using the line of code I attached not working.

Comment: Hi @neo you should use ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name). Meanwhile I updated the answer

Comment: hello @m4n3k4s , is there a way i can get something like this done as well for the RadarChart ???

Will so much appreciate your response.

Comment: for the setWebColorInner

Comment: Hi @IsraelMeshileya, did you tried extend RadarDataSet rather than BarDataSet?

Comment: I am actually using RadarDataSet..but, i did like to give each webline different color, don't know if that can be achieved @m4n3k4s

Answer (score 6):

You can find out the documentation about setting colors in MPAndroidChart from [this link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Colors)

```
    LineDataSet setComp1 = new LineDataSet(valsComp1, "Company 1");
  // sets colors for the dataset, resolution of the resource name to a "real" color is done internally
  setComp1.setColors(new int[] { R.color.red1, R.color.red2, R.color.red3, R.color.red4 }, Context);

  LineDataSet setComp2 = new LineDataSet(valsComp2, "Company 2");
  setComp2.setColors(new int[] { R.color.green1, R.color.green2, R.color.green3, R.color.green4 }, Context);
```

Comment: @AlexChengalan Can we set bar color based on entry (y-axis) value in MPAndroidChart? If not, please suggest the library which supports the same.

Comment: @Alex Chengalan Can we set bar color based on entry (y-axis) value in MPAndroidChart? If not, please suggest the library which supports the same.

Comment: How do I set the color according to the data value. Like for example if the data is less than 50 I would give green and if its more I will give red

Answer (score 5):

Thumbs up to the answer from @m4n3k4s. Just want to add some clarification with regards to these lines, since it took me a while to figure out:

```
set.setColors(new int[]{ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green), 
            ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.orange), 
            ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)});
```

I didn't know what `context` was or how to use it until I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587265/getcontext-doesnt-exist/25587433). I replaced the lines above with:

```
barDataSet.setColors(
                ContextCompat.getColor(barchart.getContext(), R.color.green),
                ContextCompat.getColor(barchart.getContext(), R.color.yellow),
                ContextCompat.getColor(barchart.getContext(), R.color.red)
        );
```

Given that `BarChart` is a subclass of `View`, and `getContext()` is a method of the `View` class.

So my complete code looks like this, where KpBarDataSet is my class that overrides BarDataSet, and DateKp is a custom class.

```
BarChart barchart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barchart);

    List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    List<String> dateLabels = new ArrayList<>();

    int i = 0;
    for (DateKp day : data) {
        // turn your data into Entry objects
        entries.add(new BarEntry(i, day.getValueY()));
        dateLabels.add(day.getLabel());
        i++;
    }

    KpBarDataSet barDataSet = new KpBarDataSet(entries, null);

    barDataSet.setColors(
            ContextCompat.getColor(barchart.getContext(), R.color.green),
            ContextCompat.getColor(barchart.getContext(), R.color.yellow),
            ContextCompat.getColor(barchart.getContext(), R.color.red)
    );
```

Lastly, `R.color.green`, `R.color.red` etc won't exist until you define them in /res/values/colors.xml.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this for 3 colors, and it worked

```
if(floatArray.get(i) >= 0.0 && floatArray.get(i) <= max1)
            {
                barColorArray1[i] = Color.rgb(0, 128, 0);           
            }
            else if(floatArray.get(i) > max1 && floatArray.get(i) <= max2)
            {
                barColorArray1[i] = Color.rgb(247, 207, 19);                
            }
            else if(floatArray.get(i) > max2 )
            {
                barColorArray1[i] = Color.rgb(199, 0, 15);              
            }
```

In this i have created an array with integer values of colors.
Lastly pass this in your `BarDataSet` as `barDataSet1.setColors(barColorArray1);`

Comment: this is easiest way to apply the custom conditions.

Answer (score 2):

here is the class for MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2

```
class MyBarDataSet extends BarDataSet {
```

```
    public MyBarDataSet(List<BarEntry> yVals, String label) {
        super(yVals, label);
    }

    @Override
    public int getColor(int index) {
        if(getEntryForIndex(index).getY() < 140)
            return mColors.get(0);
        else if(getEntryForIndex(index).getY() > 145)
            return mColors.get(1);
        else
            return mColors.get(2);
    }

}
```

Comment: where does getEntryForIndex come from??

Comment: from here "extends BarDataSet"

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

form [m4n3k4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31851986/8926845) answer

```
public class MyBarDataSet extends BarDataSet {


    public MyBarDataSet(List<BarEntry> yVals, String label) {
        super(yVals, label);
    }

     @Override
    public int getColor(int index) {
        if(getEntryForIndex(index).getY() ==40) // less than 95 green
            return mColors.get(0);
        else if(getEntryForIndex(index).getY() ==30) // less than 100 orange
            return mColors.get(1);
        else // greater or equal than 100 red
            return mColors.get(2);
    }
}
```

and in JavaCode

```
 set1.setColors(ContextCompat.getColor(StepCountsActivity.this, R.color.purple),
                ContextCompat.getColor(StepCountsActivity.this, R.color.light_purple),
                ContextCompat.getColor(StepCountsActivity.this, R.color.blue));

    }
```